# Understanding SQL Definition syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am pretty novice in writing SQL but would like to get better.  One of the things that I have never really understood is how to interpret the construct syntax for any give object.  Here is an example of OPENROWSET definition taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx.  I understand the pipe "|" represents "OR" but not sure about the other tags.  Is there a good place to learn how to interpret this?

```
OPENROWSET 
( { 'provider_name' , { 'datasource' ; 'user_id' ; 'password' 
   | 'provider_string' } 
   , {   [ catalog. ] [ schema. ] object 
       | 'query' 
     } 
   | BULK 'data_file' , 
       { FORMATFILE = 'format_file_path' [ <bulk_options> ]
       | SINGLE_BLOB | SINGLE_CLOB | SINGLE_NCLOB }
} ) 

<bulk_options> ::=
   [ , CODEPAGE = { 'ACP' | 'OEM' | 'RAW' | 'code_page' } ] 
   [ , ERRORFILE = 'file_name' ]
   [ , FIRSTROW = first_row ] 
   [ , LASTROW = last_row ] 
   [ , MAXERRORS = maximum_errors ] 
   [ , ROWS_PER_BATCH = rows_per_batch ]
   [ , ORDER ( { column [ ASC | DESC ] } [ ,...n ] ) [ UNIQUE ]
```

Comment: Check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx

Comment: @Ghost's reply is the best answer.

Comment: `[ , ORDER ( { column [ ASC | DESC ] } [ ,...n ] ) [ UNIQUE ]` there is missing `]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On every page of **Microsoft Docs** (previously MSDN) that refers to SQL Server (even about [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) there is a link called **Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions** (@Ghost post it in a comment)

[image: Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions link]

That [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will guide you to the page with explanation of SQL Syntax Conventions that you seek.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to understand this syntax is visual **`Railroad Diagram`**.

How to use it:

1. Get syntax from documentation
2. Paste to [Grammar Translator written by Colin Daley](http://www.colindaley.com/translator/Translator.aspx)
3. You may need to manually correct some errors (like missing brackets, `''`)
4. Click <kbd>Generate Railroad Diagram</kbd>
5. Learn by moving from start to end

[image]

<sup>Image generated using: https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui</sup>

---

You can also search for `Railroad Diagrams` for `SQL Server`.

[`SQL Server CREATE TABLE syntax diagrams`](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-create-table-syntax-diagrams/)

> Most important syntax:
>
> - Optional items are enclosed in square brackets
> - Groups of expressions are enclosed in curly braces
> - A '|' is a binary operator meaning 'or'.

Comment: That answer is much more accurate that mine! Thanks for the tip! I will share this sites with my colleagues who start learning SQL.